# Wubi installation sticking at almost finished copying files

Tags: installation, 12.10, wubi

I am using Ubuntu windows installer to install Ubuntu a safer way ... first time it installed correctly but due to some issues I uninstalled Ubuntu..

but now it is always sticking at almost finished copying files .. the progress bar is always at 70 percent ...

is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

1)Check whether you uninstalled it properly
2) Check for the virtual drive in the directory you first installed (if present delete that)
3) Run a registry cleaning software( eg: ccleaner)
4)Disable any antivirus / security programs
5)try installing using Wubi

P.S: Also check that the source you are using to install Ubuntu through Wubi is NOT corrupted.

Comment: what do you mean by virtual drive in a directory? well I've installed daemon tools for creating a virtual drive ....
and this I don't suppose that the source is corrupted...